# Javascript: function is returning unexpected result

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get this function to print out 4 different flags.
It's not giving me and error messages when I run it anymore, but it doesn't print my flags either.
And now I've run out of ideas to try and could really use some help.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function draw() {
        for (var draw = 0; draw < v.length; draw++) flagTarget.init()
    }

    var flagTargetElfenbenskusten =document.getElementById('flag-elfenbenskusten');
    var flagTargetSverige =document.getElementById('flag-sverige');
    var flagTargetMaruritius =document.getElementById('flag-maruritius');
    var flagTargetJapan =document.getElementById('flag-japan');


    var flagTarget = {
        init: function () {
            if (flagTargetElfenbenskusten) {
                var flagElfenbenskusten = '<div class="flag elfenbenskusten"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div></div>';
                console.log('drawing flag elfenbenskusten'),
                flagTargetElfenbenskusten.innerHTML = flagElfenbenskusten;
            }
            if (flagTargetSverige) {
                var flagSverige = '<div class="flagga1 sverige"><div class="box1"></div><div class="box2"></div><div class="box3"></div><div class="box4"></div></div>';
                console.log('drawing flag Sverige'),
                flagTargetSverige.innerHTML = flagSverige;
            }
            if (flagTargetMaruritius) {
                var flagMaruritius = '<div class="flagga2 maruritius"><div class="box1"></div><div class="box2"></div><div class="box3"></div><div class="box4"></div><div class="box5"></div></div>';
                console.log('drawing flag Maruritius'),
                flagTargetMaruritius.innerHTML = flagMaruritius;
            }
            if (flagTargetJapan) {
                var flagJapan = '<div class="flagga3 japan"><div class="box1"></div><div class="cirkel1"></div></div>';
                console.log('drawing flag japan'),
                flagTargetJapan.innerHTML = flagJapan;
            }
        }
    },

    flagTargetElfenbenskusten = Object.create(flagTarget),
    flagTargetSverige = Object.create(flagTarget),
    flagTargetMaruritius = Object.create(flagTarget),
    flagTargetJapan = Object.create(flagTarget),

    v = [
        flagTargetElfenbenskusten,
        flagTargetSverige,
        flagTargetMaruritius,
        flagTargetJapan,
        ];

    draw(),
    console.log('Sandbox is ready!')
}());
```

This is my result in the console. I don't understand why it's running 4 times either.

```
drawing flag elfenbenskusten
drawing flag Sverige
drawing flag Maruritius
drawing flag japan
drawing flag elfenbenskusten
drawing flag Sverige
drawing flag Maruritius
drawing flag japan
drawing flag elfenbenskusten
drawing flag Sverige
drawing flag Maruritius
drawing flag japan
drawing flag elfenbenskusten
drawing flag Sverige
drawing flag Maruritius
drawing flag japan
Sandbox is ready!
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A function name and variable name the same. Talk about confusing to read.

Comment: Well you call init() in a for loop so I am guessing you have for things in `v`

Comment: What does `console.log(flagTargetJapan)` give you, putting it right after `var flagTargetJapan =...`?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I've put them there from the start to see if the function was failing. I'm still very new to javascript.

Comment: I can see that wasn't clear. What I mean is, tell us what the output is. I'm wondering if, for example, `document.getElementById('flag-japan')` is finding a DOM element to write to.

Comment: Ahh! I see. I get this error message: ReferenceError: flagTargetJapan is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are always printing the result (4 times) in your loop because your test : `if (flagTargetElfenbenskusten)` will always be `true` (So the conditions will always be true).

Because you are testing if the variables aren't null and they are not null (the divs exists in the DOM), you have to change your code like this:

```
 var flagTargetElfenbenskusten =document.getElementById('flag-elfenbenskusten')textContent; // add textContent to get the value of the inputs
//do the same with the 4 variables
```

And your code should be:

```
if (flagTargetElfenbenskusten!==null) {
   // your code goes here
```

Also you haven't set any id to your divs, your final code should be:

**EDIT 2:**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
function draw() {
    for (var draw = 0; draw < v.length; draw++) flagTarget.init()
}

var flagTargetElfenbenskusten =document.getElementById('flag-elfenbenskusten').textContent;
var flagTargetSverige =document.getElementById('flag-sverige').textContent;
var flagTargetMaruritius =document.getElementById('flag-maruritius')textContent;
var flagTargetJapan =document.getElementById('flag-japan').textContent;


var flagTarget = {
    init: function () {
        if (flagTargetElfenbenskusten !== null) {
            var flagElfenbenskusten = '<div id="flag-elfenbenskusten" class="flag elfenbenskusten"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div></div>';
            console.log('drawing flag elfenbenskusten'),
            flagTargetElfenbenskusten.innerHTML = flagElfenbenskusten;
        }
        if (flagTargetSverige !== null) {
            var flagSverige = '<div id="flag-sverige" class="flagga1 sverige"><div class="box1"></div><div class="box2"></div><div class="box3"></div><div class="box4"></div></div>';
            console.log('drawing flag Sverige'),
            flagTargetSverige.innerHTML = flagSverige;
        }
        if (flagTargetMaruritius !== null) {
            var flagMaruritius = '<div id="flag-maruritius" class="flagga2 maruritius"><div class="box1"></div><div class="box2"></div><div class="box3"></div><div class="box4"></div><div class="box5"></div></div>';
            console.log('drawing flag Maruritius'),
            flagTargetMaruritius.innerHTML = flagMaruritius;
        }
        if (flagTargetJapan !== null) {
            var flagJapan = '<div id="flag-japan" class="flagga3 japan"><div class="box1"></div><div class="cirkel1"></div></div>';
            console.log('drawing flag japan'),
            flagTargetJapan.innerHTML = flagJapan;
        }
    }
},

flagTargetElfenbenskusten = Object.create(flagTarget),
flagTargetSverige = Object.create(flagTarget),
flagTargetMaruritius = Object.create(flagTarget),
flagTargetJapan = Object.create(flagTarget),

v = [
    flagTargetElfenbenskusten,
    flagTargetSverige,
    flagTargetMaruritius,
    flagTargetJapan,
    ];

draw(),
console.log('Sandbox is ready!')
}());
```

You were using `getElementById()` and you don't have any of these ids.

You don't need the for loop in your function, change it like this:

```
function draw() {
    flagTarget.init()
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

And add a call to the init method in the page load to create the flag divs:

```
window.addEventListener("load", flagTarget.init());
```

Comment: have you did it with all the variables?

Comment: Ok take a look at my EDIT, I posted the final code, you have to use `.textContent`instead of .value because yopu are using DIVS  and not inputs, I think that solves the problem.

Comment: what does it print ? What do you get in console?

Comment: Same result as in my post. No change at all

Comment: In that case you don't need the for loop in your function, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: Ok tried your last edit and it worked since now it's only doing it once. But my flags wont show.

Comment: Ah, yes of course they will not show, because the elements aren't yet created while you invoke the getElementById() , they will be created in the if block, so just add the code in my last EDIT to your page in order to create the elemnts and then show them.

Comment: It was even easier than that. I had screwed up my div id's so I was printing the flags to a content that was not longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

1. in the `draw` function you call the `init` function 4x
2. in the `init` function you pass all 4 conditions